# Is Kernel regression a good idea for time series?

Tags: time-series, nonlinear-regression, nadaraya-watson

As title. I'm worried about the implications of autocorrelation (the timeseries is not stationary), if should transform it to be stationary, etc.

Particularly worried since right now I'm having problems beating a simple Naive seasonal average model.

If I transform the series, it is not clear to me how to best compare results unless I transform back, which I can do but then it makes it harder to use backtest methods included in Darts, my framework of choice :)

Comment: There are no silver bullets.  We are mechanics in a garage, we need a good variety with each type of tool, and good ability to use each.  There are many tools good for time-series.  What exactly do you mean by non-stationary?  What does the TS look like?  What are you trying to do with it?  What are your resources?  These all feed into the selection of a "good enough" or "appropriate" approach.